# No Low Battery Notifications or Low Battery Action on 16.10/17.04/17.10/18.04.4

Tags: power-management, battery, notify-osd, 16.10, gnome-power-manager

When upgrading to 16.10 and during installation the installer seemed to turn off battery notifications and actions - I know this because I set the critical action threshold to be 15% and during installation it reached 9% (and was still on). However it seems that after installation it never turned the power settings back on.

How do I re-enable this as now my laptop doesn't inform of a low battery nor take any action on critical level?

Things I have tried:

- Reinstalling gnome-power-manager
- Reinstalling indicator-power
- Reinstalling libnotify-bin notify-osd
- Checked settings in DConf - they're all still there, just seem to be ignored.

Nothing worked. Just to clarify, this was working fine prior to upgrade to 16.10 and notifications themselves work. It just seems that power notifications and actions have been disabled.

I now have a laptop that not only doesn't inform me when the battery is low but doesn't take any action when the battery is critical. Is there a way to re-enable whatever the installer/upgrader disabled?

UPDATE: This problem still exists in 17.04, 17.10 and 18.04.4. I don't know what introduced the problem, but it sure hasn't gone away and I cannot find any way of correcting this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks! Well at least I know it isn't something that I have done then! Hopefully there is some kind of fix or workaround.

Comment: The problem still exists on 17.04 too. I was hoping an upgrade would fix it, but it didn't.

Comment: Installed 17.10 via update and now using Gnome rather than Unity - problem persists.